# Multiplication operator for scipy sparse matrices

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I'm a little bit confused by the behavior of the multiplication operator `*` when scipy sparse matrices are involved. It seems the operator implements matrix multiplication, not component-wise multiplication as it would with numpy arrays.

Some code to check this:

```
from scipy.sparse import lil_matrix
A = lil_matrix(-numpy.eye(2))
b = lil_matrix(numpy.ones((2,2)))
print (A * B).toarray()
```

results in:

```
[[-1. -1.]
 [-1. -1.]]
```

The [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html#module-scipy.sparse) of the `scipy.sparse` module does not really go into details on this, and I wonder whether there is a clear specification of the multiplication behavior somewhere?

Furthermore, are there some clearly defined rules for multiplication operator with scipy sparse matrices and numpy matrices or arrays?

Comment: I'm also looking for the some documentation about this.

Answer (score 2):

Documentation is indeed scarse. If you are looking for component-wise multiplication you can use `A.multiply(b)`, where b can be an element, vector or matrix:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.multiply.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is matrix multiplication in all cases.